# Why does sys.path start with an empty string?

Tags: python

When I print out sys.path in python it apparently always starts with apostrophes denoting an empty string '', why is that?

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
# ['', and/some/other/paths]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path),

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,
>   path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to
>   invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not
>   available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the
>   script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string,
>   which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first.